# How do I get a TextView with cursor (or an EditText never showing keypad)

Tags: android, user-input

I have a custom input panel, which I want to use to input into a text box. And I need cursor in the text box. I can think of two options-

1) A `TextView` with a cursor, to which I insert characters at the current cursor position manually. Or,
2) An `EditText`, which never trigger the soft keyboard. And I manage the input myself.

But I have not found any of this two as a working solution. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Use EditText with textwatcher and apply keyborad hide logic for begining of enter text

Answer (score 0):

You can use EditText. There are two ways to do it.

1. Simple solution is to do change in Android manifest. Add android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden" attribute to your activity.
2. In OnTouchListener for EditText, disable the input.

   MyEditor.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener(){
   @Override
   public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
   int inType = MyEditor.getInputType(); // backup the input type
   MyEditor.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NULL); // disable soft input
   MyEditor.onTouchEvent(event); // call native handler
   MyEditor.setInputType(inType); // restore input type
   return true; // consume touch even
   }
   });

Answer (score 0):

Try using EditText and in layout file add  android:focusable="false" which will prevent the keyboard to popup.

```
<EditText
     android:id="@+id/et"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:focusable="false"
/>
```

Then in code:

```
EditText et = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.et);
...
et.append("your text");
```